# change DNS or use RECORD which is better?

Tags: dns, record

To point a domain name to another host is done by either a DNS or a change in RECORD A to the second.
Are there advantages or disadvantages of one compared to another? thank you.

Comment: Umm... `A` records are part of the DNS spec. If you're changing A records, you're changing DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, the difference is pointing a user towards another domain name (DNS), or towards an IP address (A). Realistically, the A Record would be faster, as it doesn't require a DNS lookup on the extra domain, but it's negligible anyway, as once a client has looked up a DNS record it stores it so it doesn't have to do it again.

For example - Pointing example.com to example2.com (which has IP 1.2.3.4) requires the client to look up example.com, only to then have to look up example2.com to find 1.2.3.4; If you simply point it towards 1.2.3.4 in the first place, it avoids the unnecessary lookup.

This all occurs virtually instantaneously, and only once per usually 24-48 hours, so is all just academic: Realistically, use whichever is more convenient.